# Is it possible to use the latitude and longitude obtained by google places detail api to get the geonameid from the geoname table?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, geonames

Using google places API I get the geometry field that includes the latitude and longitude of a destination. Then with the latitude and longitude values I need to get the geonameid from the geoname table.

The problem is that the results for a destination obtained by google places detail API have this latitude: 40.46366700000001 and longitude: -3.74922, while for the same destination latitude and longitude in the geoname table are latitude: 40, longitude: -4

For example, Spain's data are as follows

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json\?placeid\=ChIJi7xhMnjjQgwR7KNoB5Qs7KY\&fields\=name,geometry\&key\=API-KEY
```

Output

```
{
    "html_attributions": [],
    "result": {
        "geometry": {
            "location": {
                "lat": 40.46366700000001,
                "lng": -3.74922
            },
            "viewport": {
                "northeast": {
                    "lat": 45.244,
                    "lng": 5.098
                },
                "southwest": {
                    "lat": 35.17300000000001,
                    "lng": -12.524
                }
            }
        },
        "name": "Spain"
    },
    "status": "OK"
}
```

While in geoname the latitude and longitude are the following

```
select name, latitude, longitude from geoname where geonameid = 2510769;
```

Output

- Name: Kingdom of Spain
- Latitude: 40
- Longitude: -4

The results obtained by google places detail api generally have more digits than the same data obtained from the geoname table.

How could I use the latitude and longitude obtained by google places detail api to get the geonameid from the geoname table?

Comment: Have you tried it? How? What doesn't work? How is the data stored? What type of database are you using? etc.

Comment: Also this website is full of questions like *How to find nearest place from coordinates* and the best answer will depend on your use case.

Comment: geonames data is stored in mysql, I try to know if it is possible to safely convert lat/lng as 40.46366700000001 and -3.74922 to lat/lng formats as geonames stores

Comment: How do you want to "convert" them. They are different numbers. Searching for the closest location sounds like the best approach.

Comment: I will try searching for the closest location

Comment: See my answer. Both solutions should work in your case if all you are after is the one closest entry in your db.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution:

```
SELECT geonameid
FROM geoname
ORDER BY ABS(latitude-40.46366700000001) + ABS(longitude--3.74922) ASC 
LIMIT 0,1
```

Using the Haversine formula:

```
SELECT geonameid, 
( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(40.46366700000001) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-3.74922) ) + sin( radians(40.46366700000001) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) 
AS distance 
FROM geoname 
ORDER BY distance 
LIMIT 0,1
```